# how to increase geowebcache performance with openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geowebcache

I have installed geowebcache and cached polyline data. And I am using my geowebcache data on OpenLayers map.

```
        var polyline = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "Lines",
            "http://localhost:8080/geowebcache/service/wms",
            { layers: "GIS:pipes", transparent: true, TILED: 'true', gridSet: "EPSG:94000" },
            { isBaseLayer: false}
        );
```

When I start the application my map tiles(using TMS) are coming from remote server fast. But my cache tiles(local area) are coming after my map tiles.

When I zoom in map, my wms polyline is appearing blur about 4-5 seconds then appearing clear.

I think it should be very fast because of local area and geowebcache. My server upload speed is 4MBit. And my servers are linuc OS on virtual box.

Is there any point about performance that I forget? Do you think?

Comment: Have you Preseeded your local cache with GeoWebCache?

Comment: I used rest seed page from web UI. I started seed automatically and my disk size increased 340 MB. Tiles are saved to disk.

Comment: Is that layer fast if you browse it with the demo application that comes with GeoWebCache "Automatically Generated Demos"?